# command to extract data between 2 rows

Tags: text-processing

I have to extract the exception and corresponding stack trace starting from a line number in a log file. I know the starting line no of the error. how can i find out where the stack trace will end from the below example? Appreciate your help

```
example
-------
2016-10-07 15:49:07,537 ERROR Some exception
 stacktrace line 1
 stacktrace line 2
 .
 .
 stacktrace line n
2016-10-07 15:49:07,539 debug blah blah blah
2016-10-07 15:49:07,540 debug blah blah blah
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize, you want to print lines starting with the line number that you specify and continuing until just before the first following line that starts with a date.  In your example, the starting line is 3.  In that case:

```
$ awk '{if (NR==3)f=1; else if (/^[0-9-]{10} /)f=0} f{print}' trace.log
2016-10-07 15:49:07,537 ERROR Some exception
 stacktrace line 1
 stacktrace line 2
 .
 .
 stacktrace line n
```

The above code works as follows:

- `if (NR==3)f=1`

  On the line number you specify, set variable `f` to one.
- `else if (/^[0-9-]{10} /)f=0`

  On other lines, set `f` to zero if the line starts with 10 characters that are digits or dashes followed by a space.  In other words, set `f` to zero on the first line that starts with something that looks like a date.

  If need be, we can get use more complex regexes to identify the start of a date.  For example, the following requires that the line start with something that looks like a data, followed by a space, followed by something that looks like time, followed by a comma.

  ```
  awk '{if (NR==3)f=1; else if (/^[0-9-]{10} [0-9:]{8},/)f=0} f{print}' trace.log
  ```

  Still further improvements on this are possible.
- `f{print}`

  If `f` is nonzero, print the line.

  For brevity, we could replace `f{print}` with just `f`.  This is possible because, when an action is not specified explicitly, the default action of `print` is used.

#### Alternative

Some versions of awk don't support repetition factors like `{10}`.  If that is the case on your system, try:

```
awk '{if (NR==3)f=1; else if (/^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] /)f=0} f{print}' trace.log
```

Comment: Not all the stack trace lines are intended by a space. Some of them are having a space and some of them are not.The row after stack trace begins with a date and time so is there any other way I can cut it based on that?

Comment: @Shawn That is possible.  By the way, do you want to print all stacktraces or just the one that starts on your specified line?

Comment: I need the entire stack trace.

Comment: @Shawn Let me clarify: do you want to print all exceptions+stacktraces in the file or just the one exception+stacktrace that starts on the line number that you specify?

Comment: I need the exception & stack trace that starts from the line number i specify. I do not need the entire exceptions in the file. Sorry if I confused you.

Comment: @Shawn See updated answer for a version that uses lines starting with dates to signal the end of a trace.

Comment: There seems to be some problem with the latest script. It is printing the lines starting from given line number till the end of file. Otherwise this looks good

Comment: @Shawn As you can see from the output I show, it works for me on your sample input.  If it is printing to the end of the file for you, that means that the regex `/^[0-9-]{10} /` never matched on your data.  First, what OS are you on?

Comment: @Shawn Also, try the version I just added under "Alternative" and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all stack trace lines start with a whitespace (space/tab), you can match them (`[[:blank:]]`) at the start of the line (`^`):

```
grep '^[[:blank:]]' file.log
```

Answer (score 0):

If the trace that you want to extract begins on line 2 of `trace.log`,
and its end is indicated by a line that begins
with a date in YYYY-MM-DD format
(and there are no such lines with the trace), then

```
sed -nE '2,/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} /p' trace.log
```

will print every line from line 2 *through* line *n*+3
(the first line after the trace that begins with a date). 
Since you don’t want that last line,
pipe the above into a command that removes the last line:

```
sed -nE '2,/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} /p' trace.log | head -n -1
```

or

```
sed -nE '2,/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} /p' trace.log | sed '$d'
```

If you need to search for a date *and a time*, then search for

```
^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}
```